# Need Fix for rendering in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, wordpress

How can I change the code below to render in Wordpress? Do I need to use addaction()?

```
function vsgHeading(target) {
    $(target).css.fontSize = "50px";
}

vsgHeading(".vsg-page-heading");
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No. It just doesn't work. I thought that adding addaction() and applying the function name to it would have fixed it but it did not. But then I need to make sure it only applies to that css class.

Answer (score 0):

Your vsgHeading function is created a property on a created css property of the target called fontSize I didn't know jquery could do that, may be a useful  for something.

try.

```
function vsgHeading(target) {
   $(target).css( "fontSize", "50px" );
}
```

Comment: what about addaction() to target the specific css class?

Comment: To target the <style id="css"></style> you need to target the style sheet and add a new rule ... https://usefulangle.com/post/39/adding-css-to-stylesheet-with-javascript#:~:text=Adding%20a%20New%20CSS%20Rule,rule%20to%20the%20stylesheet%20sheet.

Comment: Is the code you are trying to add to the page not being added on the host / wordpress side?

Comment: addaddition() is undefined in jquery ... add_action() exists in wordpress related to adding a callback for wordpress plugins.